# Mysql many-many join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure as followed:

I cannot post images yet, so an asssignment has many groups and many contacts, with a contact having a city and a city having a country.

I want to count countries in assignmentsassignments per group

And have following query

```
SELECT `parentCountry`.`id` as label ,count(`t`.`id`) as result, `parentGroup`.`description` as gr 
    FROM `assignment` `t` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment_contact` `assignmentContacts`
        ON (`assignmentContacts`.`assignment`=`t`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `contact` `relatedContact`
        ON (`assignmentContacts`.`contact`=`relatedContact`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `locator_city` `location`
        ON (`relatedContact`.`city`=`location`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `locator_country` `parentCountry`
        ON (`location`.`country`=`parentCountry`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment_group` `activeGroup`
        ON (`activeGroup`.`assignment`=`t`.`id`) AND (activeGroup.active=1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `group` `parentGroup`
        ON (`activeGroup`.`group`=`parentGroup`.`id`) 
GROUP BY gr,label
ORDER BY gr
```

Running this query gets me results like

```
Group1 ,Belgium, 6
Group1 ,Nederlands,3
Group2, Belgium, 1
Group2, UK,6
```

I want to get result

```
Group1 ,Belgium, 6
Group1 ,Nederlands,3
Group1 ,UK, 0
Group2, Belgium, 1
Group2, UK,6 
Group2, Nederlands,0
```

Please help, I have spend quite some hours, fiddling around with joins, to conclude that I have no 'theoretical' way of approaching this problem.

The use of UNIONS (i.e. FULL OUTER JOINS) is forbidden, but I really don't think this should be needed.

Edit: I have a horrible solution which can be

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that table with country comes first:

```
SELECT `parentCountry`.`id` as label ,count(`t`.`id`) as result, `parentGroup`.`description` as gr 
    FROM `locator_city` `location`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `locator_country` `parentCountry`
        ON (`location`.`country`=`parentCountry`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `contact` `relatedContact`
        ON (`relatedContact`.`city`=`location`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment_contact` `assignmentContacts`
        ON (`assignmentContacts`.`contact`=`relatedContact`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment` `t` 
        ON (`assignmentContacts`.`assignment`=`t`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `assignment_group` `activeGroup`
        ON (`activeGroup`.`assignment`=`t`.`id`) AND (activeGroup.active=1) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `group` `parentGroup` 
        ON (`activeGroup`.`group`=`parentGroup`.`id`) 
GROUP BY gr,label
ORDER BY gr
```

Comment: This does not work,

It just gives me a whole bunch of values:

<null,country,0> when i require <gr,country,0>

when I want the null to explicitly by the group description field

Thanks though

Comment: You probably just need to CROSS JOIN countries with groups before doing the other joins. This is the right idea.

Comment: How to crossjoin when group and countries aren't related?
tried adding CROSS JOIN group.description under FROM line, gets the same results as before

Comment: CROSS JOIN just creates a cartesian product. They don't need to be related. You do have to make sure it's done between `locator_country` and `group` though.